# ClasscastException : MyClass cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, maven, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying to set up a filter for authentication .

My Filter class is as follows

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7678740843612123432L;

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   ///Other methods...
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Map<String,String> map = getHeadersInfo(request);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
        ///Other methods.
```

The corresponding web.xml is as follows.

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mypackage.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Upon searching , I find that a lot of people face this issue because of incorrect dependencies in `pom.xml`. But Ive made sure that the corresponding jar has `provided` scope.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Other dependencies-->
```

Any thoughts on what I could be possibly doing wrong ? Links/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If it is filter, don't you need to implement Filter?http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm

Comment: Gotcha, I wasnt very comfortable with casting `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest` but it seems like there's no way around it .

Comment: Go one by one, first make sure your Filter is compiling fine, then you can work on ServletRequest to HttpServletRequest.

Comment: It works fine,thanks . But is it the best practice?

Comment: Filter for authentication? In general filters inspect request and decide next steps, they themselves don't do any authentication logic.

Comment: In addition, when you're declaring the filter, you call it AuthFilter and when mapping it, you call it LMSFilter. Not sure if typo or not.
And yes, casting to HttpServletRequest is absolutely normal.

Comment: @kaqqao: Sorry  that was a copy paste typo. Thanks for clarifying the doubt !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter should `implement` whichever `Filter` interface it purports to be, and *not* `extend HttpServlet`, unless you've combined  both functions into one class, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to add implements and didn't catch it. Thanks for this, saved me some troubleshooting time.